# REGEXP Extract value not Groups

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a word from the string which contains a specific word from the list.

For example, there is string "RR_SM_**Brand_A**_Additive_Clean_jun2020", and the list is **Brand_A, Brand_B, Brand_C** etc.

When I test RegExp, I receive 3 groups as output not 1 value (Brand_A): https://regexr.com/5tcp7

Code: `(.*)(Brand_A|Brand_B)(.*)`

I am very new to Regex and I am confused how can I extract only one value: **Brand_A**

Comment: Please post your code here, not just at regexr.

Comment: You get a group for each set of parentheses in the regexp.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Barmar code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to capture the surrounding text, leave them out of the regexp. A regular expression will match anywhere in the input.

```
Brand_A|Brand_B
```

In this case, the matches will be in group 0.

Some languages automatically anchor the regexp. In that case, you can put `.*` around this, but don't put them in capture groups.

```
.*(Brand_A|Brand_B).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple one:
`(?:Brand_A|Brand_B)`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, you need to add non-capturing group (`?:`) for your outside groups:

`(?:.*)(Brand_A|Brand_B)(?:.*)`

https://regexr.com/5tcpa

Comment: Or don't put the outside stuff in groups at all.